# Oracle SQL - REGEXP_LIKE contains characters other than a-z or A-Z

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I would like to create a query where I select all records which contain characters that are not a-z or A-Z

so something like this

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column_1, '![A-Z] [a-z]')`

Comment: IIRC, try `NOT REGEXP_LIKE()`, although that's for MySQL.

Comment: @JamWaffles If I understand, the OP is looking for results containing any non-alpha character. So a `NOT` would only return rows that contain _no_ alpha characters.

Comment: @Michael Oops! Thanks for noticing that. I feel quite silly now.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `^` negates a character class:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column_1, '[^A-Za-z]')
```

Comment: When we run that we return records such as `AB Future`.    Are we doing something wrong?  Running same query as above...   

FYI have a similar question open at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948012/oracle-query-to-find-string-not-containing-characters

Comment: @Marcus The pattern looks for _any_ character other than upper/lower letters, and your single whitespace matches. It does not enforce that the string contain _only_ non-letters. If you must ensure that _no_ non-letter characters are matched, anchor the regex like `^[^A-Za-z]+$` -- I think that's what you are asking.  The anchored pattern should not match because of the space.

Comment: Basically I'm looking to find a string which has characters _other_ than A-Z, a-z along with add'l characters like 0-9, `,`, `-`, etc.

Comment: Okay then my suggested expression should work: `^[^A-Za-z0-9,\`-]+$`  Change `+` to `*` if you would want to match a zero-length string too.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work...  doesn't return string `A b ¿C¿ d`.   No idea what that character is or how it got into the system.

Comment: When you say _other than_, do you mean _ONLY other than_?  Your column collation may impact this as well, but I don't know much about Oracle collation.

Comment: Any record where the field contains characters _other_ than those mentioned.  So `New York` should not be returned by the query.  But `New*York` should be returned (because of the `*`).

Comment: If `New*York` should be matched, then you cannot have the `^$` anchors `[^A-Za-z0-9,` -]+`

Comment: Works thanks!   Used this: `REGEXP_LIKE (mycol, '[^A-Za-z0-9, -./]+')`.   If you answer that linked question I'll accept it...

Comment: @Marcus It's just a matter of removing the anchors from the existing answer you have over there. You should accept that one after it is edited (or propose an edit)

Answer (score 10):

Something like

```
select *
  from foo
 where regexp_like( col1, '[^[:alpha:]]' ) ;
```

should work

```
SQL> create table foo( col1 varchar2(100) );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 'abc' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 'abc123' );

1 row created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 'def' );

1 row created.

SQL> select *
  2    from foo
  3   where regexp_like( col1, '[^[:alpha:]]' ) ;

COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc123
```

Answer (score 5):

if you want that not contains any of a-z and A-Z:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(column_1, '[A-Za-z]')
```

something like:

"98763045098" or "!%436%$7%$*#"

or other languages like persian, arabic and ... like this:

"خلیج فارس"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from T_PARTNER 
where C_DISTRIBUTOR_TYPE_ID = 6 and
translate(C_PARTNER_ID, '.1234567890', '.') is null;
```