# Oracle query to find string not containing characters

Tags: regex, oracle, ascii

What is an Oracle query that will return all records where the field `mytable.myname` contains *any* characters *other* than

1. `A-Z`
2. `a-z`
3. `0-9`
4. `-/\()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (myname, '^[^a-zA-Z0-9\/\\()-]+$');
```

You can also do the same with an `i` modifier:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (myname, '^[^a-z0-9\/\\()-]+$', 'i');
```

Explanation:

- `^` start of the string
- `[^___ ]` negative character set (which will match any character other than the characters specified inside it)
- `+` match the previous group more than once
- `$` end of the string

Comment: Can you help me understand that syntax?  I always struggle with RegEx.   I get that ^ means where the string is not one of these characters.  But why is there a second ^ inside the square bracket?   And what is the +$ for after the square bracket?

Comment: @Marcus `^` means start of the string.. and `[^ ]` means `not one of these characters`.. and without `+` it will match only one character.. check the update :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  Not returning this records with this data: ` ¿C¿ `

Comment: For "contains _any_" rather than "contains _all_", you should remove the start/end anchors `^...$`.

Comment: This works: `REGEXP_LIKE (mycol, '[^A-Za-z0-9, -./]+')`.   Thanks all.