# Oracle query looking for particular string format

Tags: oracle

Am working with an Oracle 11g db in which I need to run a query that returns all rows with values in a specific format.

I.e., I need to find all rows with a value like 'abc1234'. The actual values aren't important....what I need is to find all rows with the first 3 characters being alpha and the subsequent 4 characters all being numeric.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be exact since I don't have an Oracle server handy to test but something like this should get you started in the right direction:

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(your_column, '([a-z]\3[0123456789]\4', 'i')`

This will check all rows in your table where the specified column has any alphabet character A to Z three times followed by 4 numbers and return that list.  The `'i'` at the end just says ignore case on the alphabet part.  You can choose to not have that option if you so wish.

Here are a couple links as well with more information on the `regexp_like` syntax:

[Oracle SQL - REGEXP_LIKE contains characters other than a-z or A-Z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604727/oracle-sql-regexp-like-contains-characters-other-than-a-z-or-a-z)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it this will work definitely:

Let's take a sample example:

For example, create a sample table 

CREATE TABLE bob (
         empno      VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
         ename      VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL,
         ssn        VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL);

Insert data into that table

Insert into bob ( empno,ename,ssn) values ('abC0123458','zXe5378023','0pl4783202');
Insert into bob ( empno,ename,ssn) values ('0123abcdef','a12dldfddd','Rns0101010');


Query to select the all the columns 

select * from bob 
where   length(trim(translate(substr(empno,1,3),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',' '))) IS NULL 
AND 
length(trim(translate(substr(empno,4,4),'0123456789',' '))) IS NULL;



To do the same thing on multiple columns use union operator


select * from bob 
where   length(trim(translate(substr(empno,1,3),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',' '))) IS NULL 
AND 
length(trim(translate(substr(empno,4,4),'0123456789',' '))) IS NULL;
union
select * from bob 
where   length(trim(translate(substr(ename,1,3),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',' '))) IS NULL 
AND 
length(trim(translate(substr(ename,4,4),'0123456789',' '))) IS NULL;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Perhaps you could give some explanation as to how this might work and perhaps why you appear to have three copies of nearly identical code. Also, I am suspicious since `cola`, `colb`, and `colc` do not appear to be defined anywhere.